# Error creating a temporary channel using a bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I’m trying to make a script in which a user joins a certain channel, the bot creates a temporary channel and transfers the user there, and after the channel is empty, the bot deletes it, but it gives an error that the `name` value is not specified for the created channel.
I use `discord.js v14`

```
robot.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
    const voiceChannelID = '1153371417182752940';

    if (newState.channelId === voiceChannelID) {
        // Create a new voice channel
        const channel = await newState.guild.channels.create(`Channel ${newState.member.user.username}`, {
            type: 'GUILD_VOICE',
            parent: newState.channel.parent,
            name: `Channel ${newState.member.user.username}`,
        });

        // Move the user to the new voice channel
        newState.setChannel(channel);

        // Delete the voice channel when it becomes empty
        channel.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState) => {
            if (oldState.channel.members.size === 0) oldState.channel.delete();
        });
    }
});
```

I tried to find a solution to my problem in the `discord.js` documentation, but I couldn’t find anything suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discord.js docs, ([See Here](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create)) the `GuildChannelManager.create()` method takes only one parameter - "options". As well as the name issue, you may also need to set your channel type to the `ChannelType.GuildVoice`, as shown in the example in the docs.
In the above, on lines 6-10, try removing the first string parameter like so:

```
const { ChannelType } = require("discord.js");

const channel = await newState.guild.channels.create({
            type: ChannelType.GuildVoice,
            parent: newState.channel.parent,
            name: `channel-${newState.member.user.username}`,
        });
```

Do also note that this may not work for some users, as the channel name might contain an invalid string. Perhaps use their ID instead?

```
name: `channel-${newstate.member.user.id}`,
```